# Masstransit with Azure Service Bus Functions

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus, masstransit, azure-servicebus-topics

We are moving from RabbitMQ to Azure Service Bus (topic triggered functions). According to the docs, there is a new method called "AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions", but I could not figure out how to add the necessary configuration as I used to do with RabbitMQ (JsonSerializers/EntityNameFormatters), because they don't seem to be exposed.

How would this code below work inside an Azure Function?

```
Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(configureBus =>
            {
                configureBus.MessageTopology.SetEntityNameFormatter(new AcessoEntityFormatter());
                var host = configureBus.Host(new Uri(QueueSettings.AmqpConnection), config => { });
                configureBus.ConfigureJsonSerializer(settings =>
                {
                    settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                    settings.Converters.Add(new TypeNameHandlingConverter(TypeNameHandling.All));
                    return settings;
                });
                configureBus.ConfigureJsonDeserializer(settings =>
                {
                    settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                    settings.Converters.Add(new TypeNameHandlingConverter(TypeNameHandling.All));
                    return settings;
                });

                configureBus.ReceiveEndpoint(host, QueueSettings.FileReceivedSubscription, configureEndpoint =>
                {
                    configureEndpoint.Consumer<FileReceivedConsumer>(serviceProvider);
                });
            });
```

This is what I've got so far but an exception is thrown: ''SetBusFactory' can be called only once.' - Startup class:

```
.AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddConsumersFromNamespaceContaining<FileReceivedConsumer>();
            cfg.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(configureBus =>
            {
                configureBus.Host(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsServiceBus"), config => { });
                configureBus.ConfigureJsonSerializer(settings =>
                {
                    settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                    settings.Converters.Add(new TypeNameHandlingConverter(TypeNameHandling.All));
                    return settings;
                });
                configureBus.ConfigureJsonDeserializer(settings =>
                {
                    settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                    settings.Converters.Add(new TypeNameHandlingConverter(TypeNameHandling.All));
                    return settings;
                });

                configureBus.Message<FileProcessedItemEvent>(x =>
                {
                    x.SetEntityName("newmodule-fileprocesseditem-topic");
                });
            }));
```

Comment: There is a second parameter on the AddMassTransitForAzureFunctions method where you can configure the bus.

Comment: Everytime I use that second parameter and call something like :

factoryCfg.Message<NewReservationReceivedEvent>(t => t.SetEntityName("newreservationconfirmed")); 


I get an exception when the Function later calls Handle that the IoC Container is Disposed.